# Can't understand the QUORUM of the below cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra

From the cassandra [docs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html), it says for a cluster of 5 datacenters,
2 DC have replication factor 3, 3 DC have replication factor 2.
As per my understanding the quorum should be 7. But its mentioned the quorum = 6.
How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, it is `7`, the documentation is incorrect here. I am opening a ticket to get it corrected.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Also please post the link of the ticket here .

Comment: its an internal ticket but its been fixed for whenever next push is